# Reinstall SharePoint while keep all contents?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, migration, installation

I'm working on a standalone SP server. It has some issues, we decided to reinstall SP on another machine with a separated SQL server. My question is: what's the correct procedure to do this so that we can keep all sites/webs and their customizations?

Here is what I plan to do:
1) install SQL
2) install SP, make sure it has no error.
3) backup/restore content databases, attach to farm.

Will this work? One problem I may have is that some wsp may be installed on the standalone server, and we do not have access to these WSP anymore. Does it mean there is no way to restore these sites on new server (the same as before)?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally your solution will work. If you have customization stored in your 14 hive, you might want to migrate them too. I tend to forget them sometimes, when testing.

And your WSPs are still available, as long as they are available on your Farm.

I am using this script from (http://sharepintblog.com/2011/06/04/exporting-solutions-packages-wsp-with-powershell/) to export or backup our solutions.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue
## setup our output directory 
$dirName = "c:\Exported Solutions"
Write-Host Exporting solutions to $dirName 
foreach ($solution in Get-SPSolution) 
{ 
    $id = $Solution.SolutionID 
    $title = $Solution.Name 
    $filename = $Solution.SolutionFile.Name
    Write-Host "Exporting ‘$title’ to …\$filename" -nonewline 
    try { 
        $solution.SolutionFile.SaveAs("$dirName\$filename") 
        Write-Host " – done" -foreground green 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        Write-Host " – error : $_" -foreground red 
    } 
}
```